# Flutter: How to query docs in firestore based a field in an array?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to query docs based on a field from a list of custom objects in a firestore doc. Here's what the overall doc looks like:

```
  String id;
  List<AlgorandTransactionWalletData> algorandTransactionWalletData;
  AlgorandTransactionType algorandTransactionType;
  String itemId;
  int creationTimeInMilliseconds;
```

This is what an AlgorandTransactionWalletData looks like:

```
List<AlgorandTransactionId> algorandTransactionIds;
String address;
AlgorandAddressType algorandAddressType;
List<CurrencyId> currencyIds;
```

I need to get the overall firestore docs that contain the address that I'm querying for in the algorandTransactionWalletData list. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Post your a screenshot of your firestore showing the document you need and its parent collection.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact field on which you want to perform the query. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm trying to query based on the address field in the AlgorandTransactionWalletData data model from the algorandTransactionWalletData list field in the overall doc (sorry if that's confusing). If one of the instances in the list has the address I'm looking for I want to return the entire doc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you want to get all the documents (in a collection) that have that address, you query the collection using a where condition. This should fetch all documents that matches the where condition.

Below is a sample you can use. Replace COLLECTION_NAME with the name of the documents collection.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('COLLECTION_NAME')
  .where('address', isEqualTo: queryAddress);
// where queryAddress is the address you want to find.
```

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and explanation

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the answer with more explanation. Is it okay now?

Comment: yes, that's much better, pay attention to next time. We thrive to make every answer and question on the site as clear and informative as can be to make it easy for people who run into the same problems to be able to understand to issue cause and resolution